# XQuery - Problem with map merging - Execution xbase

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am very new in xquery and I have a problem, that I can't get solved.

I want to iterate a xml and save some entries in a map. So that I can merge the same keys with different values (StringValue1, StringValue2). At the end I want to return the complete map and save it to a file. Following you find my code. And I using xbase to execute these xquerys.

**CODE**

```css
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";

(: Function should merge the values, if the map contains the key, else it should put the new entrie to the map.:)
declare function functx:pnMap($map as map(*), $key as xs:anyAtomicType, $value as item()*) as map(*) {
    if(map:contains($map, $key)) then (map:merge(($map, map{$key:$value}), map{"duplicates":"combine"})) else map:merge((map{ $key: $value }, $map))
 } ;
 
let $pnMap := map{}

for $x in doc('file:///D:/Software/BaseX932/basex/input/MyXML.xml')/PFA/Records/Entity
return functx:pnMap($pnMap, substring-before((substring-after(data($x/BigUnsortedStringField), 'Owner: ')), '
'), string-join(('Position=Owner | ', 'EntityID=', data($x/@id),' | ', 'SomeOtherNo=', data($x/IDNumberTypes/ID[@IDType="StringWhereIfindsomeOtherNumber"])), ''))
```

**RESULT**

```css
map {
  "Nick": "Position=Owner | EntityID=625115 | SomeOtherNo=7206512"
}
map {
  "James": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016624 | SomeOtherNo=9138056"
}
map {
  "Nick": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016625 | SomeOtherNo=9051648"
}
map {
  "Pete": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016626 | SomeOtherNo=9051636"
}
map {
  "Jon": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016675 | SomeOtherNo=9349667"
}
```

**Expected Result 1**

```css
map {
  "Nick": "Position=Owner | EntityID=625115 | SomeOtherNo=7206512, Position=Owner | EntityID=1016625 | SomeOtherNo=9051648"
  "James": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016624 | SomeOtherNo=9138056"
  "Pete": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016626 | SomeOtherNo=9051636"
  "Jon": "Position=Owner | EntityID=1016675 | SomeOtherNo=9349667"
}
```

This is an abbreviated excerpt from the XML:

```xml
<Entity id="1016626">
  <Status>Active</Status>
  <IDNumberTypes>
    <ID IDType="SomeOtherNo">
      <IDValue>9051636</IDValue>
    </ID>
  </IDNumberTypes>
  <BigUnsortedStringField>Some text
    Owner: Pete
    Sister: Magrit
    Next Line text
    more text
  </BigUnsortedStringField>
</Entity>
<Entity>
....
</Entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
map:merge(
  doc('file:///D:/Software/BaseX932/basex/input/MyXML.xml')/PFA/Records/Entity ! 
    map:entry(
      substring-before(substring-after(BigUnsortedStringField, 'Owner: '), '&#10;'),
      string-join(('Position=Owner', 'EntityID=' || @id, 'SomeOtherNo=' || IDNumberTypes/ID[@IDType="StringWhereIfindsomeOtherNumber"]), ' | ')
    ),
  map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' }
)
```

but it is hard to write code without seeing the XML input.

As an alternative you could also try to use XQuery group by first on the data you want and then create the map of the result of the grouping:

```
map:merge(
  for $entity in doc('file:///D:/Software/BaseX932/basex/input/MyXML.xml')/PFA/Records/Entity
  group by $owner := substring-before(substring-after($entity/BigUnsortedStringField, 'Owner: '), '&#10;')
  return
    map:entry($owner, string-join(
$entity!string-join(('Position=Owner', 'EntityID=' || @id, 'SomeOtherNo=' || IDNumberTypes/ID[@IDType="StringWhereIfindsomeOtherNumber"]), ' | '), ' , '))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont know, where I have to copy it. I get the error: Excepting function argument. -.-

Comment: Did you try to first version before the edit? That had a syntax error as I got lost in the nesting of functions calls. I think both the latest versions should not give syntax errors. I might have misinterpreted the structure of your text data, I guess instead of `substring-before(substring-after(BigUnsortedStringField, 'Owner: '), ',')` you want `substring-before(substring-after(BigUnsortedStringField, 'Owner: '), '&#10;').

Comment: I got, what I want. Thank you man. :)
My biggest problem of xquery is to understand the syntax. Evertime it need a return, but I dont want to give a return. :D